# Solve ODE: $xy''(x) + xy'(x) + by(x) + cxy(x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The only way I can think of to solve this is to use confluent hypergeometric functions which is a bit impractical with the things I need to do with it afterwards. Is there any other way of solving this which describes y with a simpler function?

Comment: I went at it with laplace transform, and while it was possible, it was definitely not easy. Gave up midway. I think there may be a "simpler" solution, but it's still not a "simple" one, if that makes any sense.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to be viable with Laplace transform, but I'll give it a try. I don't really mind the solution being long if it's expressed in terms of a simpler function.